# Are high-current (over 3 A) PWMs common?

Tags: pwm, components, high-current

I have a motor whose speed I wish to control using PWM. The starting current is 11 A and the normal current is 3 A, with a rated voltage of 22 V.

I want to find a PWM controller with an output current over 3 A, but out of the over 1000 PWM controllers on Farnell, [only 30](https://uk.farnell.com/w/c/semiconductors-ics/power-management-ics-pmic/pwm-controllers?output-current=3a%7C5a%7C8a%7C10a%7C13a%7C500a&range=inc-in-stock&st=pwm) had an output current reaching 3 A or above, and only 11 had an output current reaching 10 A, most of which were mislabelled.

Are PWM controllers reaching over 1 A very uncommon? Should I look into building my own?

Comment: A PWM means 'a pulse width modulation', which doesn't make sense as a noun. Do you mean a PWM driver or PWM controller? If so, please can you edit your question to fix that. Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for the wrong thing.   Do a search on Amazon for "Motor Speed Controller".  There are dozens made to handle all the DC amps you could want.

Comment: Example     https://www.amazon.com/RioRand-7-80V-Motor-Controller-Switch/dp/B071NQ5G71/ref=sr_1_5?crid=3PCIY0CPCI9J4&keywords=motor+speed+controller&qid=1666042703&qu=eyJxc2MiOiI1LjU2IiwicXNhIjoiNC43OSIsInFzcCI6IjQuNTcifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=motor+speed+controller+%2Caps%2C92&sr=8-5

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PWM controllers are commonly used to drive transistors to switch high-current loads. That way, the controller itself only needs to provide enough current to switch the transistor (usually an N-channel MOSFET, requiring just a short pulse of current to charge the gate; you can also use a gate driver to further reduce the current demand on the PWM controller). By using large enough transistors, you could control arbitrarily large currents with them.

It sounds like what you want is a *motor driver*, which usually has a PWM controller at its core, along with switching transistors and other components needed to control a motor, all integrated into a single IC.

You also see this same technique used in every type of DC-DC converter, where a PWM controller is at the core of the DC-DC controller, which also has other features integrated on the same die (such as the necessary feedback and reference components).

Answer (score 8):

The PWM controllers you have linked on Farnell can be used in power supplies (for example) but also can be used for motors. However, they all require that the output pin be connected to a power transistor so that appropriate power currents (up to maybe 100 amps and beyond) can be controlled. The first device on your Farnell list: -

[image]

I suspect that if you focussed on the problem you are trying to solve rather than asking a question about a potential solution, it might all become very clear.